# Operator Semigroup: Resolvent estimates and stabilization, a detail in the paper of Nicoulas Burq and Patrick Gerard

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, spectral-theory, semigroup-of-operators

In **Appendix A** of the paper **Stabilization of wave equations on the torus with rough dampings** https://msp.org/paa/2020/2-3/p04.xhtml or https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.00983 by Nicoulas Burq and Patrick Gerard.

The author states a equivalent relation:

Supposed that $e^{tA}$ is a strongly continuous semigroups on a Hilbert space $H$ with infinitesimal generator $A$ defined on $D(A)$. The following two properties are equivalent:

(1) There exist $C,\delta>0$ such that the resolvent of $A$, $(A-\lambda)^{-1}$ exists for the real part of $\lambda$, $\rm{Re}\ \lambda\geq-\delta$ and satisfies $\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{C}^{\delta}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\rm{Re}\ z\geq-\delta\}$, we have $\|(A-\lambda)^{-1}\|_{\mathscr{L}(
H)}\leq C$.

(2)There exist $M,\delta>0$ such that for any $t>0$, $\|e^{tA}\|_{\mathscr{L}(
H)}\leq Me^{-\delta t}$.

Confusion of the proof: When proving $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$, the authors say "Since $v(t)$ is supported in $t\in[-1,0]$, the right side hand in $(i\tau+\omega-A)\hat{u}(\tau)=\hat{v}(\tau)$" is holomorphic and bounded in any domain $\mathbb{C}_{\alpha}=\{\tau\in\mathbb{C}:\rm{Im}\ \tau\geq\alpha,\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\}$($\color{red}{why?}$)."

In the next line, the authors say:

"From the assumption on the resolvent, we deduce that $\hat{u}$ admits a holomorphic extension to $\{\tau: \rm{Im} \tau\leq\delta+\omega\}$ which satisfies $\|\hat{u}(\tau)\|_{H}\leq C\|\hat{v}(\tau)\|_{H}$($\color{red}{why?}$)"

Why should we consider the holomorphic extension of $\hat{u}$(**the time fourier transform of $u$**)
thank you very much!!!!

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460219/operator-semigroup-resolvent-estimates-and-stabilization-a-detail-in-the-paper This question has been answered in the above link.